# angular 7+ ionic 4 Can't bind to 'datasets' since it isn't a known property of 'canvas'

Tags: angular7, ionic4, ng2-charts

I am getting the error when trying to use ng2-charts with Angular 7 and ionic 4.

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ChartsModule
  ],
```

Any hint will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Charts Module on a sub Module or a different page ?

Comment: @RanikaNisal Thanks I didnt include it in the sub module where it is used.